# Maven intermediate parent pom

Tags: maven

I have a multiple module java project where all the dependencies are being managed by the parent pom, `<DependencieManager>`, as usual.

80% of those modules belongs to a certain category and they have the same dependencies, it means I need to duplicate the same dependencies, plugins and repositories sections in all those module’s poms.

In order to avoid such duplication I decide to create an intermediate parent that contains such sections and make those modules use this intermediate parent as its parent making the modules to ’inherit’ those sections.

Everything compiles and runs ok... the problem comes when I try to create the artifacts. `mvn package` doesn’t create an artifact from this intermediate parent since it a `<packaging>pom</packaging>`

Is there any way to accomplish what I’m trying to do here?

Comment: Sorry, I do not really understand the question. The intermediate parent POM is of packaging POM (naturally), so it creates a POM. What else do you expect?

Comment: If you define `<packaging>pom</packaging>` that means you don't create an artifact in the meaning of jar, war ear etc. but of your you create an artifact `pom`...can you please create an example project which shows the problem/setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem on having a intermediate parent pom module to control dependencies was at time to assembly. The maven-assembly-plugin doesn't allow to have an empty archive.

The solution was to exclude artifacts of the type `pom` in the descriptor file:

```
(...)
<dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>*:pom</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </dependencySet>
</dependencySets>
(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

A plea to appeal to sanity:

**Parent POMs that contain dependencies should only contain the common dependencies amongst child projects.**

In your project, if you have subprojects A and B which both need commons-lang, then it's not unreasonable to put that into the parent project.

In your project, if you have subprojects A and B, and only A requires a PostgreSQL dependency, B should absolutely not be pulling that in as a part of its dependencies.

The issue seems to stem from the way in which you've structured your POM.  *Enough* things needed similar dependencies that it was okay to put them in the parent project, but now things are getting a bit out of hand and tougher to manage.

Each project should be responsible for its own dependencies, and while I can respect the desire to avoid duplication, in my head it's far more desirable to avoid having an artifact pull in more than it absolutely needs.

Comment: The best is to have only dependencyManagement in parent-poms never use dependencies cause these dependencies are always inherited which is in the majority of the case not what you want ...there are exception of that ...

Comment: So, you mean that, in my case, duplicating dependency, plugin and repository sections among +-30 modules is something that I have to live with, right?

Comment: @VeryNiceArgumentException:  I never mentioned anything about plugins or repository sections.  I wouldn't imagine that you'd have to put those into child projects at all, unless the child project needed some specific plugin config that its children couldn't supply.  And again, I stress that you should be putting ***common*** dependencies in the parent project.

Comment: @Makoto' plugins and repositories are in the same bucket. Those 80% of the modules that I mentioned also have specific plugins and repositories and they also need to be duplicated in each module. I cannot tread them as common enough to be put in the parent project because the other 20% of the modules don't need them.

Comment: For most of the plugins you can easily activate/deactivate them through a `skip` property., like `my.plugin.skip`. We have lots of plugins defined in our company parent POM which are skipped. If somebody needs them, he/she sets the `my.plugin.skip` to `false`.

Comment: For repositories, these are usually not defined in the POM, but in the `settings.xml`.

Comment: So dependencies are really the only larger thing we are talking about. For them, you can also define a `common-dependencies.pom` and use it as a dependency in all the places where these `common-dependencies` are needed. We have this situation for portlets. Each and every portlet (we have about 60) needs a set of five dependencies, and we wrote a POM for that which just lists these five.